# set ipython's default scientific notation threshold

Tags: python, printing, formatting, ipython, output

How can I modify the point at which python decides to print in scientific notation?

E.g. I'd like everything `> 1e4` or `< 1e-4` to be printed in scientific notation.

Good:

```
In [11]: 5e20
Out[11]: 5e+20
```

Bad:

```
In [12]: 5e10
Out[12]: 50000000000.0
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In IPython you can use

```
%precision %.4g
```

this will print floating point values who's absolute value is < 1e-4 or >= 1e4 in scientific notation.

You can find more information about the `%precision` command in the [IPython API Docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-precision).
For string formatting options have a look at the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  (Note: I don't think there should be quotations there).  Is there anyway to make this the default behavior (or load it everytime I run ipython)?

Comment: Add (or edit) the line `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['%precision %.4g']` in IPython's configuration file. To locate the file use `ipython locate`. In my case it was under `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` (see [IPython Doc](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/overview.html#ipython-dir)). Thanks for pointing out the quotations, I'll remove them :-).

Comment: This solution no longer seems to work (IPython 2.2.0 / RHEL7 / Python 2.7.5).  It continues to print out scientific notation for values that do not meet my requested threshold.

Comment: I just tried it out with Python 2.7.9 and IPython 2.4.0 and it still works for me.

Comment: This is a [Jupyter "magic" instruction](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-precision), and does not work for Python used in Spyder.