# Force ipython to output in scientific notation

Tags: python, ipython

Is it possible for force ipython to output in scientific notation, or set the threshold at which it switches to scientific notation?

For example,

```
In [26]: 1000000000000

Out[26]: 1000000000000
```

But I want:

```
In [26]: 1000000000000

Out[26]: 1e12
```

Can I do this? I saw an old answer to this from years ago but it does not appear to be working anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [set ipython's default scientific notation threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866761/set-ipythons-default-scientific-notation-threshold)

Comment: There is no threshold at which IPython will print *ints* in scientific notation. Floats, sure, but not ints. Printing ints in scientific notation would be ambiguous, making them look like floats.

Comment: @NagabhushanSN that doesn't answer the question. The solution no longer works. In ipython if I type %precision %.3e and then 1000000000000. it still outputs as 1000000000000.0

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I find the same behavior when trying to output 100000000.0

Answer (score 2):

just you do formatting like this:

```
print("{:e}".format(12300000))
```

output:

```
1.230000e+07
```

Comment: That works but I'd like that to be the default behavior in ipython output.

Comment: formatting is the only option. IPython notebook doesn't have this option right now.